# How can I store the user name from a back channel event in a variable?

Tags: node.js, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I've built a SharePoint chat bot using v4 of the Bot Framework and NodeJS and I'm running into a bit of a problem where I am trying to store the user name of an event that's being sent to the Bot from the Client using the back channel.

The Bot outputs the user name as expected, but it doesn't seem to be stored in the Bot when I'm trying to call it via a variable. When I look at the Bot console log, all that's displayed is the ID and none of the event information.

The objective with this is to store the user name in a variable, so when a user completes a form in the Bot, the name has been captured.

Here is the Client application in SharePoint I'm using to send the user name via the Directline backchannel.

```
private _showPanel = (): void => {
this.setState({ showPanel: true });

// Get the user name
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties", false);
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.send();
var user = { id: "userid", name: "unknown" };
if (req.status == 200) {
  var result = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
  user.id = result.Email;
  user.name = result.DisplayName;
  var userName = user.name
  console.log("Bot loaded for "+userName)
}

directLine
.postActivity({ type: "event", name: "SendUserInfo", text: user.name, from: { id: "userid" } })
.subscribe(id => console.log("Backchannel event success"));
 };
```

The Bot is listening for the event in the DialogBot.js file

```
// Listen for the event 'SendUserInfo' and store the user name in a variable
this.onEvent(async (context, next) => {
  if (context.activity.name === 'SendUserInfo') {
            var userName = await context.sendActivity(context.activity.text);
            console.log(userName);
        }
        await next();
    });
```

I'm trying to call that variable in my functionaDialogBase.js file so it can be used when the user submits a form

```
const { userName } = require('../dialogbot');
{...}
 var authCtx = new AuthenticationContext(settings.siteurl);
 authCtx.acquireTokenForApp(settings.clientId, settings.clientSecret, function (err, data) {

var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("/sites/demosite");
authCtx.setAuthenticationCookie(ctx);
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('BotBookings');
    var creationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var listItem = list.addItem(creationInfo);
    listItem.set_item('UserName', userName);
    listItem.set_item('Title', title);
    listItem.set_item('SessDate', booksessjson2);
    listItem.set_item('SessTime', booksessjson3);
    listItem.update();
    ctx.load(listItem);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync();
    });
```

When I complete the form, the userName field is blank and I'm expecting to see the user's name in that column.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, but I solved this in the end rather simply. If anyone else runs into a similar issue, I used the exports function. So instead of

```
// Listen for the event 'SendUserInfo' and store the user name in a variable
this.onEvent(async (context, next) => {
if (context.activity.name === 'SendUserInfo') {
        var userName = context.activity.from.id;
        console.log(userName);
    }
    await next();
```

I used

```
// Listen for the event 'SendUserInfo' and store the user name in a variable
this.onEvent(async (context, next) => {
 if (context.activity.name === 'SendUserInfo') {
        exports.userName = context.activity.from.id;
        console.log(userName);
    }
    await next();
```

I was able to call the string using;

```
const { userName } = require('fileref').userName
```